# Creating and referencing a table of tables

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a mysql database table called Vehicles.
This table has many rows: car, helicopter, plane, etc.

I want each of these rows to have their own table, so I can have different data for each vehicle type.

My question is, how can I make this table so that each row references not another row on another table, but the table itself. I thought of just using the table name, but it feels a bit hackish.

Comment: Not that I condone having a separate table for each type of transportation yet, but you could just have VehicleID as a foreign key. It's value would be the same for every record in the table though...

Comment: the problem is that they have very different attributes, so I guess I need a separate table for each one.

Comment: I'd give serious consideration to if you would need to query for all vehicles regardless of type  If so separate tables will be a pain unless you have a main table for all vehicles and the sub tables simply contain additional attributes needed for each type.  This this could also be accomplished through a few tables attribute (List of all attributes for any vehicle beyond base class), VehicleTypeAttribute (List of attributes relevant to each type and it's datatype, VehicleAttribute (list of user defined values for each vehicleTypeAttribute..)

Comment: yes, the idea is to have sub-tables with additional attributes.. I just have no idea how to properly link or reference them.. both using the table name and a foreign key on all fields seem "ugly" solutions.. how do the pros do this?

Comment: Wouldn't it be a 1-1 relationship between vehicleID?  As far as how do pro's do it... A view, dynamic SQL, use of a procedure... use left joins to sub tables, procedure calling different selects depending on the "Types of vehicles" so you only left join what you need to...  It's different data and different columns.  So the SQL will have to be different.  Or you have to do the above and flatten the design, and handle the different data types.  Both approaches have been used.  Purest in database will tell you to write separate tables and queries  coders will tell you that's too much overhead.

Answer (score 0):

If I'm reading this correctly, you are thinking of a Base or Master entity table to hold all attributes that the vehicles have in common, then a derived table for all the attributes associated with each vehicle.

Something like this maintains data integrity and is scalable:

```
create table Vehicles(
    ID      int not null auto_generated primary key,
    VType   char( 1 ) not null check( VType in( 'C', 'H', 'P' )),
    ...     <other common attributes>,
    constraint UQ_ID_VType unique( ID, VType )
);
create table cars(
    ID      int not null primary key,
    VType   char( 1 ) not null check( VType = 'C' ),
    ...     <other car-only attributes>,
    constraint FK_Car_Vehicle foreign key( ID, VType )
         references Vehicles( ID, VType )
);
create table Helicopters(
    ID      int not null primary key,
    VType   char( 1 ) not null check( VType = 'H' ),
    ...     <other helicopter-only attributes>,
    constraint FK_Helicopter_Vehicle foreign key( ID, VType )
         references Vehicles( ID, VType )
);
```

Etc. The Vehicles table can contain only defined vehicle types and each sub-table can only contain their particular vehicle type and each ID/Type combination must exist in Vehicles first. Beyond that, each one can define any attributes it needs to describe its particular vehicle type. To add Motorcycle, add 'M' to the check constraint of VType field of Vehicles table and create a Motorcycles table with 'M' as the only acceptable value of *its* VType field.

If all you have is the vehicle ID value, you locate that in the Vehicles table to find out the type -- car, helicopter, etc. -- and that tells you which sub-table to access to get the rest of the information.

As an alternate, and it helps with the scalability factor, have the VType field of the Vehicles table be a FK to a VehicleTypes table. Then you don't have to redefine the table itself to add a new type of vehicle.